# How can I simulate / test deployment on different Java Application Servers?

Tags: java, deployment, enterprise

I am currently developing something in Java using Jetty as my web container. How can I test if  my WAR/EAR/etc file can be deployed on other servers (including enterprise level servers)?

I want to try and sell my application to enterprises, but not sure how I can know whether or not the application will deploy? I've only ever used OS servers before

Also how do I spec my 'system requirements' if i don't have access to enterprise grade hardware?

edit: I mean, if I look at something like this: http://wiki.gxtechnical.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Oracle+Application+Server+Deployment, it looks deceptively easy.. But going in blind is quite scary!

Answer (score 0):

You need to download, configure, and install each server and try it out. Many have free or limited development versions.

Depending on the complexity of your application, you will very likely encounter issues with each container. I can't say if any of them will be in conflict (i.e. fix it to work with container X makes it break in container Y), but it is possible.

Comment: I see, thanks. So can I get my desktop, install unix and glassfish server and deploy it to a local address. If that works then it's more or less as good as I can get?

Comment: That can work fine. A lot of folks are also using VMs for this kind of work, like VMWare or VirtualBox.

Comment: Good idea! Might save me a lot of extra work actually. Cheers Will